# JUnit Custom Rules

Tags: junit, junit4

JUnit 4.7 introduced the concept of custom rules:

http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/07/junit-4.7-rules

There are a number of built in JUnit rules including TemporaryFolder which helps by clearing up folders after a test has been run:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();
```

There's a full list of built in rules here:

http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/package-summary.html

I'm interested in finding out what custom rules are in place where you work or what useful custom rules you currently use?

Comment: Looks like this should be community wiki as it asks for a plethora of responses none of which is right.

Answer (score 2):

I used *@Rule* for repeated test: [@Rule: 在JUnit4中利用Rule](http://blog.csdn.net/michaellufhl/archive/2010/10/20/5955098.aspx)

Sorry, It's Chinese, but code and comment are English:)